# AWS EC2 reaches high CPU uses during nighttime

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I just implemented a few alarms with CloudWatch last week and I noticed a strange behavior with EC2 small instances everyday between 6h30 and 6h45 (UTC time).

I implemented one alarm to warn me when a AutoScallingGroup have its CPU over 50% during 3 minutes (average sample) and another alarm to warn me when the same AutoScallingGroup goes back to normal, which I considered to be CPU under 30% during 3 minutes (also average sample). Did that 2 times: one for zone A, and another time for zone B.

Looks OK, but something is happening during 6h30 to 6h45 that takes certain amount of processing for 2 to 5 min. The CPU rises, sometimes trigger the "High use alarm", but always triggers the "returned to normal alarm". Our system is currently under early stages of development, so no user have access to it, and we don't have any process/backups/etc scheduled. We barely have Apache+PHP installed and configured, so it can only be something related to the host machines I guess.

Anybody can explain what is going on and how can we solve it besides increasing the sample time or % in the "return to normal" alarm? Folks at Amazon forum said the Service Team would have a look once they get a chance, but it's been almost a week with no return.

Comment: Is it defintely a small instance, or is it a micro instance?

Comment: Small instances. Just went to check to make sure of it.